# Array of Pointers getting garbage value in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to create an array of pointers to a 2D (5 X 12) array in C++.
The ptr array has 5 elements. Each element should hold the address of the 1st element of the respective row of the 2D array. So 1st element should point to 1st element of 1st row, 2nd element should point to 1st element of 2nd row, and so on.
The 5th element of my array of pointers seems to point to a garbage value.

Code and output shown below. Can anyone please let me know why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
   int rainMatrix[5][12] = {{0}}; //declare and initialize rain matrix
   int *matrix_ptr[5] = {NULL};//declare and initialize array of pointers
   int **matrix_ptr_ptr = matrix_ptr;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      matrix_ptr[i] = &rainMatrix[i][0];

   rainGen(matrix_ptr_ptr, 5, 12); //generate a random matrix

   //display the matrix
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 12; ++j) {
         cout << setw(2) << rainMatrix[i][j] << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
      cout << setw(2) << *matrix_ptr[i] << "  " << rainMatrix[i][0] << endl;

   return 0;
}

void rainGen (int **pptr, int row, int col)
{
   unsigned int seed = 43;
   unsigned int rv;

   srand(seed);

   for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            rv = rand() % 100;
            **pptr = rv;
            *pptr += 1;
        }
        pptr++; 
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
11  1
88  11
28  88
25  28
1477892712  25
```

Comment: Am I reading this right?  Are you setting your pointer to a random value in rv = rand() % 100;  **pptr = rv; ?

Comment: @DenizC No, he's setting the contents of the pointer to a random value.

Comment: @JesperJuhl, true. I forgot to delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the pointers in the pointer-array `matrix_ptr` within your `rainGen` function, so that all of them point past the end and further accesses go to "random" memory locations, which is *undefined behavior*. Tools like valgrind can find such errors.

Comment: Specifically, the statement `*pptr += 1;` is doing the trick, so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

You're manipulating the wrong pointer in the innermost loop. Consider the pointer arithmetic carefully:

- `pptr` essentially points to `matrix_ptr[0]`;
- on the *first* iteration, the double indirection means `**pptr` will set what you want, but then
- `*pptr += 1` will modify the contents of `matrix_ptr[0]`, which means *it no longer points to the beginning of the matrix*.

Subsequent passes through the loop compound the situation drastically.

Modifying `pptr` won't help because it actually points to the wrong thing: it points to `matrix_ptr`, so incrementing it **merely once** moves its address from that of `matrix_ptr[0]`, which points to `rainMatrix[0][0]`, to that of `matrix_ptr[1]`, which points to `rainMatrix[1][0]`. That is the wrong address for the next entry of the matrix, which is `rainMatrix[0][1]`. In essence, you've moved to the next row, instead of to the next column.

Try this for the innermost loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    {   
        auto qptr = *pptr;
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
        {
            rv = rand() % 100;
            *qptr = rv;
            qptr += 1;
        }
        pptr++;

    }
}
```

In this case, `qptr` is given the address of the first entry in the matrix. `*qptr = rv` sets the value. `qptr += 1` increments the position of `qptr` while leaving `*pptr` alone - and, by extension, it leaves `matrix_ptr[0]` alone.

Answer (score 1):

John Perry correctly identified the problem, but you have several option to deal with it. You are incorrectly incrementing `*pptr += 1` Beyond using `auto`, you can simply index the pointer with the offset of `j`, e.g.

```
*(*pptr + j) = rv;
```

or

```
(*pptr)[j] = rv;
```

Either will work. Putting it together in your `rainGen` function, you could do:

```
void rainGen (int **pptr, int row, int col)
{
    unsigned int seed = 43;
    unsigned int rv;
    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
            rv = rand() % 100;
            // *(*pptr + j) = rv;   /* or */
            (*pptr)[j] = rv;
        }
        pptr++;
    }
}
```

(**note:** `seed` and `srand(seed)` should be moved to `main()` if there is the potential that `rainGen` could be called more than once -- `srand` should only be called once)

**Example Use/Output**

Both will produce the desired output:

```
$ ./bin/raingen
72 71 65 94  0 13 49 17 36 49 67 51
87 68 45 15 91 72 16 80 77 35  9 81
11 88 73 59 24 22 37 48 45 54 94 45
19 44 62 56 45 81 59 32 49  4 99 92
28 16 24  5  3 34 38 14 22 12 26 98
72  72
87  87
11  11
19  19
28  28
```

Comment: The main point of my answer is not so much `auto` but the use of `qptr`. While equivalent to your answer, I think that both makes the intent clearer to a less-experienced programmer and is less prone to pointer arithmetic errors like this one.

Comment: Agreed. I was just messing with this section when you posted your answer. Impressed. `auto` wouldn't have been my first thought, but worked fine. The combination should give a clear picture. Thanks.